# How can we get video upload log in vimeo API

Tags: video, file-upload, vimeo-api

I am trying to upload video which is near about 16GB and I am using vimeo API for upload video. Some time my upload is hangout in 16-20%. So I want a way which can help me to find out any upload bug. Please reply back soon.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the user's weekly upload quota on vimeo? If not, you could take a look [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos).

**For Simple HTTP POST uploading**

You would receive a response from the vimeo server. There is a field named `uri`. According to vimeo there should be some kind of process information: `The API endpoint for your upload ticket. You can query this to learn more about the upload.`

**For Resumable HTTP PUT uploads / Streaming**

Here you make a `PUT` request to the vimeo server. You will receive the following information from vimeo server:

```
Successful uploads with have a HTTP 200 status code. 
A 501 error means you did not perform a PUT or the request was malformed.
```

Using this method you could also request the current status of the upload, so you could resume the upload from where you stopped.

**Automatic PULL update**

Using this method I think you could not receive some kind of log information.

I hope this could help you. I haven't personally do not have any experience with Vimeo uploading. Just following their guide, but if you have more questions, I'll be happy to help, if I can

Comment: We have purchase unlimited membership plan which is allow us to upload video without any weekly upload limit So I think weekly upload quota is not a problem at all... any other option?

Comment: Vimeo has listed 3 ways for uploading a video: a HTMP POST, Streaming or via a pull from the vimeo server. Which one have you chosen?